# fscanf not reading from file

Tags: c, file, scanf

im trying to read some input from my txt file but i dont know why its not reading ...
What am i doing wrong ?

Content of the file : 
        3 1.0
        0.05 0.2 0.5

Function to read :

```
float * le_dados_ficheiro(char *nomeFich,int *nMoedas, float *valor)
{
   FILE    *f;
   float *p,*q;
   int     i;

   f = fopen(nomeFich,"r");
   if(!f)
   {
       printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro %s\n",nomeFich);
       exit(1);
   }

   fscanf(f," %d %f",nMoedas,valor);//**It is empty after this**

   p = malloc(sizeof(float)*(*nMoedas));
   if(!p)
   {
       printf("Erro ao reservar memoria ... \n");
       exit(1);
   }

   q = p;
   for(i = 0; i < *nMoedas; i++)
       fscanf(f," %f",q++);

   fclose(f);

   printf("%f -  %f  - %f",q[0],q[1],q[2]);//**Still empty**
   return q;
    }
```

Comment: Formatting is moch better now,...and please show the exact verbatim content of your file.

Comment: Why are you asking about a failing fscanf() without coding a check on its return value and reporting what it tells you?

Comment: i already tried to check , and its not giving error

Comment: You don't. Read in `man fscanf`: RETURN VALUE
       On  success, these functions return the number of input items successfully
       matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or  even  zero,
       in the event of an early matching failure.

Comment: Michael Walz , should i do this even if both variable are pointers ?

Comment: @Kelve forget my wrong (now deleted) comments and look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply printing the wrong data here:

```
printf("%f -  %f  - %f", q[0], q[1], q[2]);
```

`q` points after the end of your array. You need to print `p`:

```
printf("%f -  %f  - %f", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
```

Otherwise your program works providing the exact content of your file is this:

```
3 1.0
0.05 0.2 0.5
```

Correct code with error checking:

```
float *le_dados_ficheiro(char *nomeFich, int *nMoedas, float *valor)
{
  FILE  *f;
  float *p, *q;
  int i;

  f = fopen(nomeFich, "r");
  if (!f)
  {
    printf("Erro ao abrir ficheiro %s\n", nomeFich);
    exit(1);
  }

  if (fscanf(f, " %d %f", nMoedas, valor) != 2)
  {
    printf("Wrong  file format ... \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  p = malloc(sizeof(float)*(*nMoedas));
  if (!p)
  {
    printf("Erro ao reservar memoria ... \n");
    exit(1);
  }

  q = p;
  for (i = 0; i < *nMoedas; i++)
  {
    if (fscanf(f, " %f", q++) != 1)
    {
      printf("Wrong  file format ... \n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  fclose(f);

  printf("%f -  %f  - %f", p[0], p[1], p[2]);
  return q;
}
```